# How to use Throttle Concurrent Builds in Jenkins Declarative Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have Jenkins declarative pipelines for a few different repos that trigger a database refresh, and unit tests that depend on the database. These Jenkins jobs are triggered from pull requests in GitHub.

To avoid resource collisions, I need to prevent these jobs from running at the same time -- both within each project, and across projects.

The "Throttle Concurrent Builds" plugin seems to be built for this.

I have installed the plugin and configured a category like so:

[image: TCB system configuration]

And I added the "throttle" option to the Jenkinsfile in one of the repositories whose builds should be throttled:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    options {
        throttle(['ci_database_build'])
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            parallel {
                stage('Build source') {
                    steps {

                        // etc etc...
```

However, this does not seem to be preventing 2 jobs from executing at once. As evidence, here are 2 jobs (both containing the above Jenkisfile change) executing at the same time:

[image: Two throttled jobs running at the same time]

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @nogenius I have not found the solution to the throttling problem, but I have implemented a solution to the broader database collision problem:

Every job creates a new database with a random name, configures the code to use that database, and then deletes the database in the post { always {} } step of the pipeline. This has the added benefit of allowing multiple jobs to execute concurrently while maintaining resource separation.

Comment: What a pitty (for me) - good for you though. Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following in the options block should work

```
options {
    throttleJobProperty(
        categories: ['ci_database_build'],
        throttleEnabled: true,
        throttleOption: 'category',
    )
}
```

The full syntax can be seen here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin/pull/68)

Comment: Nice one!  I was searching for this block for more than 6 hours. Small correction, last line shouldn't end with ,

Comment: i know this is old, but this this actually work for you? it didn't for me

Comment: Also didn't work for me, ignores the category config and runs unlimited amount of concurrent jobs

Comment: Beware that there is a bug in the throttle-concurrent-builds plugin where the: *maxConcurrentPerNode* is not respected for declarative pipelines.
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-49173. Took me a long time to find out why the previously provided solution did not work.